# How would you draw the NFA Language x*?

Tags: automata, nfa

I am learning about automata, and we are now learning about NFAs, my professor told us to write an NFA for some language x*, as I understands * means that if you also have no input the language should be accepted, so when I made the NFA, in this case the start stage would also be the final stage my professor told me it is wrong because it would have any sense to make a automata that accepts on nothing, am I in the wrong here?

Comment: I believe you are correct, if you have the language (a+b)*, it should only be one state, which is the start and the final state. If the * was a +, then it should be in two stated minimum

Comment: When you say some language x*, is x ... a symbol in some alphabet? or, some alphabet? or, some arbitrary language (set of strings)?